# how to add a missing letter in the list

Tags: asp.net

i have a list of a - z and i am generating a bar that shows something like this:

`a b c d e f g h i j k l m n ...... z`

right now i display a character that exists in the the database for an example if the name is exists something like this `Alan` then i am displaying the character `A`

but if I dont have anybody with the name starts with `B` then its now displaying currently.

instead i want to show `B` even thou it does not exists in the db, how would i do that?

here is my code:

```
      List<char> HeaderOf = new List<char>();

protected void ListItem(List<Customer>.Enumerator cust)
{
    if (cust.MoveNext())
    {
        Customer t = cust.Current;
        string[] list = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "v", "z" };
        var output = list.Aggregate("", (current, listitem) => current + (Environment.NewLine + "<h1 id='" + listitem.ToUpper() + "'><span>" + listitem.ToUpper() + "</span></h1>"));

        char CheckMe = t.Name.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper()[0];
        if (!HeaderOf.Contains(CheckMe))
        {
            HeaderOf.Add(CheckMe);

            l = new Literal();
            l.Text = "<h1 id='" + CheckMe + "'><span>" + CheckMe + "</span></h1>" + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use Repeater control:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <h1 id='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>' ><span><%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %></span></h1>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

private const string ABCString = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        protected void Page_Load(object  sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Repeater1.DataSource = ABCString;
                Repeater1.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to create one function to enumerate through the customers.
then another function to build the literal to enumerate through the array of letters

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what your asking for. Why don't you just display the letters A - Z onto the page. Then, when the user clicks on a letter, you then perform a query which returns the names of people which start with that letter (if that is what your intention is).